# Eager to move up from Mint 19 to ubuntu Maté

Tags: system-installation, usb, mate, mint

Sorry if this the wrong place.

My first computer was the Timex Sinclair 1000 back in the day. and I loved learning the language for it, but after many huge improvements in my subsequent computers, a very bad thing happened... windows. With that, the magic stopped. Well, I'm old now, early 60s, and last week I decided I had to get rid of windows along with google and all their products. I suppose you all know that google is more difficult to divorce than windows, but it is often the #1 computer resource hog in most win based systems. Yes, both google-search and gmail are second to none and is why I keep chrome around during this abrupt transition, though their replacements are soundly structured.

I come to you with my simple question, but please believe me that I have worked all through the night trying to salve it without help, and I'm sure in time I would figure it out, but I'm more anxious than ever to get this done and it is a new day.

I started with slamming in Mint 19, kicking out windows, thank God... It was sooo easy. But now I'm faced with a dilemma. In moving up to ubuntu Maté, I must find a "USB-stick boot Installer" to burn in the ubuntu Maté OS. This was no problem when moving from windows to Mint 19, because all boot installers accommodated windows. But now, I can't seem to find one that is built for Linux Mint. Well, there was UNetbootin, but for some odd reason, I could not get it to run effectively.

Because the memory is only 3.7 GB and HDD 479.8 GB, I downloaded your 18.04.1 LTS {Bionic} release.

By the way, the laptop I'm currently using is a 5-year-old with the following specs:

---

System: Host: robert-HP Kernel: 4.15.0-36-generic x86_64 bits: 64 gcc: 7.3.0

CPU: Quad core Intel Pentium N3540 (-MCP-) arch: Silvermont rev.8 cache: 1024 KB flags: (lm nx sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 ssse3 vmx) bmips: 17326

clock speeds: min/max: 499/2665 MHz 1: 499 MHz 2: 499 MHz 3: 851 MHz 4: 721 MHz

Graphics:  Card: Intel Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx Series Graphics & Display bus-ID: 00:02.0 chip-ID: 8086:0f31 Display Server: x11 (X.Org 1.19.6 ) drivers: modesetting (unloaded: fbdev,vesa) Resolution: 1366x768@60.03hz OpenGL: renderer: Mesa DRI Intel Bay Trail version: 4.2 Mesa 18.0.5 (compat-v: 3.0) Direct Render: Yes

Audio: Card Intel Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx Series High Def. Audio Controller driver: snd_hda_intel bus-ID: 00:1b.0 chip-ID: 8086:0f04 Sound: Advanced Linux Sound Architecture v: k4.15.0-36-generic

Drives: HDD Total Size: 504.1GB (5.6% used) ID-1: /dev/sda model: TOSHIBA_MQ01ABF0 size: 500.1GB serial:  ID-2: USB /dev/sdb model: STORE_N_GO size: 4.0GB serial:

Info: Processes: 245 Uptime: 4:09 Memory: 2920.6/3835.4MB Init: systemd v: 237 runlevel: 5 Gcc sys: 7.3.0 Client: Unknown python3.6 client inxi: 2.3.56

---

This is an old laptop I'm using while the keyboard of my usual Sager gaming notebook is being replaced, taking a week or so. I'm not interested in updating this old laptop, though the prospect of using its windows OS is terrible, so now it has Mint 19.

I hope you understand. With Linux, the magic is back!

OH! P.S.  I'd like to thank Joe Collins and his EzeeLinux program. Imma Texan too Joe.

UPDATE!!!
I was finally able to install ubuntu Maté once I realize that the .iso.torrent, being recommended, was the wrong choice for me. It was the straight .iso file below it that had the command need to burn it to the USB stick. https://gyazo.com/bf9698778ddc566feb51bf805c091121

Comment: please don't write novels when your question is as simple as "*Where to find a USB-stick boot Installer for Linux Mint*". Unfortunately, this is about Linux Mint which is not supported at ask**ubuntu**.

Comment: So the essence of your question is "I must find a "USB-stick boot Installer" to burn in the ubuntu Maté OS. This was no problem when moving from windows to Mint 19, because all boot installers accommodated windows. But now, I can't seem to find one that is built for Linux Mint. Well, there was UNetbootin, but for some odd reason, I could not get it to run effectively." Correct?

Comment: Afaik, there is **USB image writer** or something similar for Linux Mint.

Comment: There's also Etcher as an AppImage but I use `mkusb` but that requires the poster to add a ppa.

Comment: My first post was long, sorry for using it as a partial introduction. I'm thrilled that I now have ubuntu Maté now installed and updated on this laptop, though it's resources as so thin that the Linux OS eventually freezes, making it necessary to hit the power button to shut it down. I haven't been so excited with technology from the time windows was first made generally available. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

Welcome to askubuntu. :)

On mint, you can Right-click the ISO file and select Make Bootable USB Stick, or launch Menu ‣ Accessories ‣ USB Image Writer. (see https://linuxmint-installation-guide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/burn.html)

If you want, you can also buy pre-written usb sticks for mate ubuntu on https://www.osdisc.com/products/ubuntumate?affiliate=ubuntumate

To create a USB stick on ubuntu, you can type `usb-creator-gtk` into a terminal.

Comment: https://gyazo.com/bf9698778ddc566feb51bf805c091121  Here is where I went wrong by accepting the official Ubuntu MATE recommendation to download the .iso.torrent instead of the straight .iso that was beneath it. The .iso.torrent file, of course, has no "Make Bootable USB Stick" as does the straight .iso file has. This mistake caused me to believe the install file, being recommended by the Ubuntu MATE official site, must have been meant for a windows environment. So I searched high and low for a Linux version of a boot installer.

Comment: By the way, I would like to be shown in the assumed "duplicate" question where it mentions my original questioning of "now I'm faced with a dilemma. In moving up to ubuntu Maté, I must find a "USB-stick boot Installer" to burn in the ubuntu Maté OS. This was no problem when moving from windows to Mint 19, because all boot installers accommodated windows. But now, I can't seem to find one that is built for Linux Mint."
I was asking here, where might I find a Linux compatible "USB-stick boot Installer". That was the specific problem, to avoid the prevailing windows versions.